# Setting parent attributes in child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, subclassing

It has just dawned on me that I can set an attribute of a child class that only it's parent uses

```
In [34]: class A:
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         pass
    ...:
    ...:     def a(self):
    ...:         print(f'b = {self.b}')
    ...:
    ...: class B(A):
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         super(B, self).__init__()
    ...:         self.b = 1
    ...:

In [35]: b = B()
    ...: b.a()
b = 1
```

This implementation seems counterintuitive and something feels wrong about it but I'm not quite sure what it is.

I would think that the following makes more sense

```
In [38]: class A:
    ...:     def __init__(self, b):
    ...:         self.b = b
    ...:
    ...:     def a(self):
    ...:         print(f'b = {self.b}')
    ...:
    ...: class B(A):
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         super(B, self).__init__(1)
    ...:

In [39]: b = B()
    ...: b.a()
b = 1
```

Are there use cases where the former would be a more recommended implementation than the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, you are doing two different things. In the first case, you have something like an *abstract* class; in other words, a base class which is not meant to be instantiated alone, because the definitions of certain attributes are "missing"; it is understood that subclasses will implement those attributes.

The more idiomatic way to do something like this would be to mark `A` as an *abstract base class* using the `abc` module, for example:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self):
        pass

    def print_me(self):
        print(f'x = {self.x}')

class B(A):

    @property
    def x(self):
        return 1

A().print_me()
```

The output will then be:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class A with abstract methods x
```

On the other hand, this works:

```
B().print_me()  # prints x = 1
```

By doing this, you signal clearly that a subclass *must* override the `x` property, otherwise the `print_me` function won't work.

Moving to the second case, you have a concrete base class and subclass, with the subclass acting something like a constraint on the nature of instances that can be created. In this case, a standalone instance of `A` is perfectly valid; it is just that instances of `B` provide the additional guarantee that a specific attribute will always be a certain value (or, at least, be initialised to a certain value, if you intend your class to be mutable).